# SQL Query between two tables and only return entries from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to create a query between two tables but only matches from one specific table.
This is what I've tried so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM dbo.table1, dbo.table2
WHERE dbo.Table1.Field1 = dbo.Table2.Field1
```

It's currently returning many duplicates and a ton of records that don't even meet the matching criteria.
I only want to return matches from Table1 that meet the criteria

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: This is a start. Thank you!

Comment: You have asked for `*`, which will return all columns in all tables in the `from` clause. if you only want columns from one table you can specify that by prefixing it, ie, `select distinct dbo.table1.* from ...`. But you also shouldn't really use `*`. Specify the columns you want explicitly. You should also alias your tables in the from clause, it will make your life much easier: `select distinct t1.somecolumn from dbo.table1 t1 join dbo.table2 t2 on t1.field1 = t2.field1` (note the use of `join`, not `where`, to do the join, per marc_s's comment).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your join is duplicating rows, if you want to return columns from `table1` only then possibly you need to use `exists`:

```
select <columns>
from dbo.table1 t1
where exists (select * from dbo.table2 t2 where t2.field1 = t1.field1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT [t1].*
FROM [dbo].[table1] [t1]
JOIN [dbo].[table2] [t2] ON [t2].[Field1] = [t1].[Field1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT t1.* -- or list of columns from table1 instance(t1)
FROM 
    dbo.table1 as t1 
left join
    dbo.table2 as t2
ON dbo.t1.Field1 = dbo.t2.Field1;
```

See the different types of joins and use the appropriate one that matches with your scenario.